Sharded Discord.js bot resets to initial presence status
I wrote a Discord.js bot in NodeJS that uses discord-hybrid-sharding to spawn my bot.js. 
In the bot.js code below, you can see that I have an initial status of "Starting..." and then in ClientReady I set the actual status.
However, seemingly at random, my bot just goes back to the initial "Starting..." status. It operates completely normally though. I assumed it could be that a shard died or something, but why would that kill my interval? The check I tried to do in the Interval sadly doesn't work.

When I restart my pm2 process for the bot, the status gets correctly set for a while again, but then randomly goes back to "Starting...".

Sharding Manager (app.js) that starts bot.js:
import { ClusterManager } from "discord-hybrid-sharding";
import { config } from "../config/config.js";

const manager = new ClusterManager("./src/bot.js", {
    totalShards: "auto",
    shardsPerClusters: 2,
    token: config.discord.bot_token,
});

manager.on("clusterCreate", shard => console.log(`Launched shard ${shard.id}`));

manager.spawn({ timeout: -1 });

bot.js that sets the status:
import { ClusterClient, getInfo } from "discord-hybrid-sharding";
import DiscordClient from "discord.js";

const client = new DiscordClient({
    presence: {
        status: "dnd",
        activities: [{ name: "Starting...", type: ActivityType.Playing }],
    },
    shards: getInfo().SHARD_LIST,
    shardCount: getInfo().TOTAL_SHARDS,
});

client.cluster = new ClusterClient(client);

client.on(Events.ClientReady, async() => {
    const guildCount = await client.guilds.fetch().then(guilds => guilds.size);

    client.user?.setActivity({ name: `Counting on ${guildCount} servers!`, type: ActivityType.Playing });

    let lastGuildCount = guildCount;
    setInterval(async() => {
        const newGuildCount = await client.guilds.fetch().then(guilds => guilds.size);
        const statusHasReset = client.user?.presence.activities[0].name === "Starting...";

        if (newGuildCount !== lastGuildCount || statusHasReset){
            lastGuildCount = newGuildCount;
            client.user?.setActivity({ name: `Counting on ${newGuildCount} servers!`, type: ActivityType.Playing });
        }
    }, 45 * 60 * 1000);

    client.user?.setStatus("online");
});

(unrelated parts of the code have been omitted. Full code, if required, is at https://github.com/NullDev/Arithmetica-Bot)
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Someone on the Discord.js Discord helped me:
Moving my setInterval logic to the shardReady event did the trick. 
This event is called once the bot starts, and also every time a shard restarts. 
Unlike ClientReady which is only called a single time on bot start.
const setStatus = async function(client, count){
    client.user?.setActivity({ name: `Counting on ${count} servers!`, type: ActivityType.Playing });
    client.user?.setStatus("online");
};

client.on(Events.ClientReady, async() => {
    const guildCount = await client.guilds.fetch().then(guilds => guilds.size);
    await setStatus(client, guildCount);
});

client.on(Events.ShardReady, async shard => {
    const guildCount = await client.guilds.fetch().then(guilds => guilds.size);
    await setStatus(client, guildCount);

    let lastGuildCount = guildCount;
    setInterval(async() => {
        const newGuildCount = await client.guilds.fetch().then(guilds => guilds.size);

        if (newGuildCount !== lastGuildCount){
            lastGuildCount = newGuildCount;
            await setStatus(client, newGuildCount);
            Log.info("Guild count changed to " + newGuildCount + ". Updated activity.");
        }
    }, 10 * 60 * 1000);
});

